# How to control Arduino frequency?

Tags: arduino, frequency, delay

I'm porting a code from c in the Arduino platform (I'm using an [Arduino Leonardo](http://store.arduino.cc/eu/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=11_12&products_id=225)). I wanto to remote control a camera with an IR LED. The info about the remote control want to emulate [here](http://www.doc-diy.net/photo/rc-1_hacked/). The code, [here](http://www.doc-diy.net/photo/eos_ir_remote/index.php).

The Burst frequency to drive the IR LED is 32700 Hz, and i'm trying to make Arduino runs at this frequency.

I've not an engeneering background so i don't really know what to do. I think i need some kind of delay to make Arduino run at that frequency, there is a note on the frequency in the second link i gave:

> Before compilation, the microcontroller clock frequency must be
>   specified [...]
>
> In case the IR light is visible and the camera not responding: [...]
>   check the program timing. The _delay_us() routines in the code need a
>   proper setting of the F_CPU variable.

EDIT: i'm posting because i have tried the code in [here](http://controlyourcamera.blogspot.de/2010/01/automatically-resume-video-shooting-on.html) but it seems to be some communication problem with the IR signal emitted: not every time the LED blink (i have tested with a cellphone cam and it blinks at specified times) the camera is shooting.

Comment: I don't have a time for a proper answer, but I have few comments: 1. If you want to generate signal at 32 kHz, you don't want to run the Arduino at that frequency. The F_CPU parameter is used to calculate for how long the Arduino should wait before doing more processing. [Here](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Learning/Atmega83-3V)'s a link which describes the changes. The examples there change the F_CPU from 16 MHz to 8 MHz (which is opposite of what you want to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your example is written for a 7.9MHz clocked CPU:

```
#define F_CPU 7900000 // clock frequency, set according to clock used!
```

Whereas Arduino runs at 16MHz. Since all delays in the code `_delay_ms(HPERIOD);` are in milliseconds, you should be just fine by deleting that first `F_CPU` line from the source and recompiling it. Arduino automatically uses the correct frequency for for your board (16MHz).

Comment: ok thank you! Anyway, i have found interesting to try to made arduino runs slowly. can you add in the answer some more generally point on how to make arduino runs at different hz?

Comment: If you want the processor to run at different frequencies, you'll have to change the crystal, and you're not ready to do that yet.

Comment: Changing the clock frequeny will break the bootloader. You won't be able to load new programs on the Arduino.